# How two NAT'ed Skype nodes communicate

Tags: p2p, skype

"The video/voice communication through Skype is established through UDP. The trick here is that quite often, one of the users is behind a firewall or a router, hence it doesn't have a real IP address. But if both Skype clients are on real IPs, then the media traffic flows directly between them over UDP..."

**"If one of the callee or both of them do not have a public IP, then they send voice traffic to another online Skype node over UDP or TCP."** Can anyone explain this statement. I did not understanf how they manage to find each other?

Article Source: http://EzineArticles.com/496462

Article Source: http://EzineArticles.com/496462

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clients can communicate via Skype login server and supernodes.

More details about Skype protocol:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skype_protocol